# NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSelectionList

Tags: javascript, angular, components

The whole error is this: NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[MatSelectionList -> MatSelectionList -> MatSelectionList]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatSelectionList!

I don't really understand what is happening, I have this element in another component and it works without issues, I'm definitely importing it,  this is my module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SidenavComponent } from './sidenav.component';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { SidenavItemModule } from './sidenav-item/sidenav-item.module';
import { ScrollbarModule } from '../../components/scrollbar/scrollbar.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { IconModule } from '@visurel/iconify-angular';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-alerts';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [SidenavComponent],
  imports: [
    AlertModule.forRoot({maxMessages: 4, timeout: 3000, position: 'right'}),
    CommonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    SidenavItemModule,
    ScrollbarModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    IconModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  exports: [SidenavComponent]
})
export class SidenavModule {
}
```

Edit:

I'm a dumbass, the problem wasn't on the module, it was actually on the HTML, I wasn't using the mat-selection-list portion of it and just listing the mat-list-option.

```
 <mat-selection-list #shoes [multiple]="false">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" [value]="shoe">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error clearly indicates that angular is looking for the `MatSelectionList` but couldnt find it. Install Augury ( chrome plugin ) and check the component hierarchy, you will find the module from where `MatSelectionList` missing. If you dont want to install Augury then check the project structure and see if you have any parent child relationship in between components.
Give it a try, I am sure you will resolve this error quickly.